# MCMC: why params that are directly sampled from posterior converge slower than that sampled from Metropolis steps

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, state-space-models

I am fitting a Bayesian model (the core is a linear state space model) using MCMC. Most of the parameters are sampled directly from their analytic posteriors whereas the left are sampled from Metropolis steps. In many situations I am surprised that the some of the former parameters converge slower than the later. May I ask is it normal? What is possible reason of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole chain converges at the same time. Thus you can think of the chain converging at the rate of the slowest component.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me this. Yes, it turns out whole chain is not converged (though some of the parameters "seem" converged).